# Selectively disable "Try it out" in swaggerUI

Tags: reactjs, redux, swagger, swagger-ui

Although there is a long discussion on the topic here: https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/issues/156

I have not found a cleaner way to 'selectively' disable the "Try it out" button.
I want to disable it for all the POST methods of my API.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Which version of Swagger UI - 2.x or 3.x?

Comment: Please, take a look at the following thread if you are using OAS 3.x
https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/issues/3725

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Swagger UI 3.10.0+ and 2.x provide the [`supportedSubmitMethods`](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/blob/master/docs/usage/configuration.md#network) option to control which HTTP methods have "try it out" enabled (default = all).

To disable "try it out" for POST (but not PATCH/PUT):

```js
// index.html (Swagger UI 3.10+)

const ui = SwaggerUIBundle({
  url: "http://my.api.com/openapi.yaml",
  supportedSubmitMethods: ["get", "delete", "options", "head", "patch", "trace"], // No "post"
  ...
})
```

To disable "try it out" for all methods except GET and HEAD:

```js
  supportedSubmitMethods: ["get", "head"],
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using OpenAPI you can control it via environment settings which is good if you have multiple installations

This for example enables only get and put verbs.
SPRINGDOC_SWAGGER_UI_SUPPORTED_SUBMIT_METHODS=get,put

See https://springdoc.github.io/springdoc-openapi-demos/springdoc-properties.html for list of verbs (just the usual http verbs)