# Swagger UI disable Try It Out button

Tags: swagger-ui

I would like to disable `Try it Out` button in the API documentation. I have tried `"tryItOut": false` in the parameter and the configuration. Furthermore, I'm using swagger 2.0 which has 'Try it out' button is enabled by default and in 3.0 it is disabled by default. So, there should be option to configure it. How to disable `Try it out` button from the Swagger UI?

Comment: Related: [Selectively disable “Try it out” in Swagger UI](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47860927/113116)

Comment: The flag is called "tryItOutEnabled", not "tryItOut"

Comment: @Alkanshel despite the name, the `tryItOutEnabled` config does NOT disable the "try it out" functionality. This config is used to display operations in the "try it out" mode by default so the users only have to click "Execute" (instead of "Try it out" followed by "Execute") to send requests.

Comment: Ah, I thought that's what was being requested

Answer (score 18):

Set [`supportedSubmitMethods`](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/blob/master/docs/usage/configuration.md#user-content-supportedsubmitmethods) to an empty array `[]` in your Swagger UI configuration. This config option is supported in v. 3.10.0+.

```js
const ui = SwaggerUIBundle({
  "dom_id": "#swagger-ui",
  url: "https://path/to/your/api.yaml",
  ...
  supportedSubmitMethods: []    // <--------
})
```

This config can also disable "Try it out" selectively for specific HTTP methods. For example, `supportedSubmitMethods: ["get", "head"]` keeps "Try it out" only for GET and HEAD, but disables it for POST, PUT, PATCH, DELETE and other methods.

Comment: Is it possible to remove methods, instead of adding maybe 100 of methods?

Comment: They're talking about HTTP methods, i.e. GET, PUT, POST, DELETE, etc.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods

There are only 10 HTTP methods.

Answer (score 9):

In Swagger UI Options, try this for .NET 6 or 7:

```
    app.UseSwaggerUI(options =>
    {
        options.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "My API");
        options.EnableTryItOutByDefault();
    });
```

Comment: The relevant Swashbuckle option is actually [`.SupportedSubmitMethods(..)`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57490187/113116). `.EnableTryItOutByDefault` does not disable the "try it out" functionality (which is what the OP wanted), it has [another purpose](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68312431/swagger-ui-disable-try-it-out-button/68313189#comment131135151_68312431).

Comment: @Helen The context of the question is confusing because `disable Try It Out button` may be first thing to search for in order to find how to "bypass the need to click on the button all the time", so in context of "clicking "Try it out" for no good reason is so annoying" the `EnableTryItOutByDefault` is correct answer

Answer (score 1):

From the GitHub repository comments, the bellow code works to me

```
const DisableTryItOutPlugin = function() {
  return {
    statePlugins: {
      spec: {
        wrapSelectors: {
          allowTryItOutFor: () => () => false
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

// elsewhere, when you call Swagger-UI...
SwaggerUI({
  plugins: [
    DisableTryItOutPlugin
  ]
})
```

Reference: https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/issues/3725#issuecomment-334899276

Comment: While the plugin still works, now there's a built-in `supportedSubmitMethods` config for that.

Comment: could you please share more details on how you implemented this?