# How can i disable the "Authorize" and "try it out" buttons in the L5 Swagger package templates?

Tags: laravel, swagger, swagger-ui, l5-swagger

Having these pieces of functionality makes sense for our app in local and staging but not in production. I'm trying to find a place to add logic to remove these buttons but it doesn't look like the blade view gets exported with the package.

For the try it out, which is the most important I went into the config and set tryItOutEnabled to false, example below. the setting isnt disabling or removing the try it now button, I did confirm other settings were working when I changed them so this seems odd to me.

```
  'ui' => [
        'display' => [
            /*
             * Controls the default expansion setting for the operations and tags. It 
                can be :
             * 'list' (expands only the tags),
             * 'full' (expands the tags and operations),
             * 'none' (expands nothing).
             */
            'doc_expansion' => env('L5_SWAGGER_UI_DOC_EXPANSION', 'none'),

            /**
             * If set, enables filtering. The top bar will show an edit box that
             * you can use to filter the tagged operations that are shown. Can be
             * Boolean to enable or disable, or a string, in which case filtering
             * will be enabled using that string as the filter expression. Filtering
             * is case-sensitive matching the filter expression anywhere inside
             * the tag.
             */
            'tryItOutEnabled' => false,
            'filter' => env('L5_SWAGGER_UI_FILTERS', true), // true | false
        ],
```

Questions:

1. How can I remove the Authorize button from the top of the page?
2. How can I remove the "Try it out" functionality in production, or for every environment?

Comment: I don't think to expose your swagger in production is a good idea, especially if you remove the Authorization functionality. You can override your templates to achieve what you want

Comment: With regard to disabling "try it out", the relevant Swagger UI config is [`supportedSubmitMethods`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68313189/113116), which needs to be set to an empty array. Does L5-Swagger provide access to this config?